# Pascal isDir function

Tags: php, freepascal

I want to make a program that lists files contained in a certain directory. I want to list the file and only the file, not the folders that is on this directory, too. How can I do this in Pascal? If in PHP, there is a function named "isDir", which return true if the parameter specified is a directory(folder). Using this function, I could check whether the "path" I'm using is a file or a folder.

Now, I am using the FindFirst and FindNext procedure to get all files/folders in the directory.

```
program mine;
uses dos;

var F: SearchRec
begin
    readln(dir);
    FindFirst('dir+'\.*.',anyFile,F);
    while DosError=0 do begin
        writeln(F.Name);
        FindNext(F);
    end;
end.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
while DosError=0 do begin
        if ((F.attr and faDirectory) <> faDirectory)
         then  writeln(F.Name);
        FindNext(F);
    end;
```

Sorry my Pascal is a bit rusty

Basically the object returned by FindFirst/FindNext contains an ATTR property which indicated the type of file it is.

Also, at the end of your loop, be sure to add a FindClose() call to free the memory

```
FindClose(F)
```

File attribute constants

- faDirectory-Is directory
- faReadOnly-Readonly file
- faArchive-Archive bit
- faHidden-File is hidden
- faVolumeId-File is the volumne ID
- faSysFile-System File

Comment: The faDirectory is a constant value defined by Delphi that allows you to test attributes of the file.   Each file has attributes ( readonly, archive bit, etc.) and faDirectory is another one.

Comment: Ah, I see. 'faDirectory' is replaced by 'directory' in pascal, though... it looks like that for every file attribute constants in delphi, the "fa" prefix is not included in pascal.

Comment: Sorry, saw Pascal and thought Delphi.   Glad you got it work though

Answer (score 0):

If you use free pascal, afaik Sysutils has "directoryexists"